# Standard output of a C program run in a subprocess not showing up on EC2 instance

Tags: c, python-3.x, gcc, amazon-ec2, subprocess

I am running a Python service that runs a C program in a subprocess. The standard output(printf statements within the program) of the C program shows up in real-time when I run it locally on my laptop but doesn't show up when I run it on an EC2 instance (Linux AMI).

I see the log of the subprocess getting created but nothing after that.

Any suggestions on why this could be happening? This C program runs for a long time, and I need to see the output for debugging purposes.

EDIT:

As asked, I'm adding some more context and example commands:

To compile the C file:

```
subprocess.call(["gcc", "cfile.c", "-ocfile", "-lm","-mcmodel=medium"])
```

To run:

```
subprocess.call(["./cfile", str(args[0])], stdin=sys.stdin)
```

When I run this locally on my Macbook, it runs the 'cfile' and prints all the printf statements on the terminal.

[image]

However, when I run this on a Linux EC2 instance it runs but doesn't print the printf statements, as seen in this picture.

Is this because when this runs on EC2, I have logged in as ec2-user but this runs for root user?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @kaylum I have added more information